# Есть ли макрос или WinAPI функция, которая бы выводила число в десятичной системе счисления. На подобии print(eax), а eax было равно 76.123

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Затрудняюсь с выводом вещественных чисел. Как это можно сделать в masm легко?
Если нет такого макроса, то просто как легко вывести вещественное число в консоль в masm?
Можете пожалуйста показать реализацию, а то я новичок в ассемблере

Comment: `printf()` из msvcrt.dll со спецификатором `%f`

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать реализацию, а то я не могу понять как написать это

Comment: у меня нет масма, а только fasm для Win32/64. если разберётесь - могу привести пример.

Comment: Да, можете пожалуйста на fasm показать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Да, можете пожалуйста на fasm показать

У функции `printf()` из **msvcrt.dll**:

Спецификатор `%f` выводит данные типа **"float"**; `%lf` это **"double"**; а `%Lf` это тип **"long double"**.
Так-же можно ограничивать числа до и после точки.
Например спецификатор `%.8lf` выведет 8-знаков после точки.
Вот пример:

```
format   pe console
include 'win32ax.inc'
entry    start
;//----------
.data
temp      dq   76358997432.100235
;//----------
.code
start:  cinvoke  printf,<10,' Result: %.8lf',0>,dword[temp],dword[temp+4]
        cinvoke  getch
        cinvoke  exit,0
;//----------
section '.idata' import data readable
library  msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
import   msvcrt,printf,'printf',getch,'_getch',exit,'exit'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё пример, только на этот раз с функцией `scanf()` для ввода вещественного числа с клавиатуры, поле чего число умножается в сопре FPU на 2, и произведение выводится на консоль:

```
format   pe console
include 'win32ax.inc'
entry    start
;//----------
.data
temp     dq   0.0    ;// буфер для ввода
two      dd   2.0    ;// множитель
;//----------
.code
start:  cinvoke  printf,<10,' Type float digit: ',0>
        cinvoke  scanf,<'%lf',0>,temp

        finit             ;// clear fpu stack
        fld     [temp]    ;// ST0 = введённое число
        fmul    [two]     ;// множитель
        fstp    [temp]    ;// сохранить с очисткой стека

        cinvoke  printf,<' Fmul(2) result..: %lf',0>,dword[temp],dword[temp+4]
@exit:  cinvoke  getch
        cinvoke  exit,0
;//----------
section '.idata' import data readable
library  msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
import   msvcrt,printf,'printf',scanf,'scanf',getch,'_getch',exit,'exit'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]